# Incompatibility in WebSite on Windows 8 IE - site doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, crash, incompatibility

I'm with a problem that could not fix  on my own.

I have this WebSite (ASP.NET) running out on a virtuam machine. The webSite was OK.....til I figure out one thing...

The applications doesn't work on IE of the Windows 8, and I don't know why.

Here's the description of the error:

"cookieless forms authentication is not supported for this application"

The system does use cookies for keep users data. The web.config file is was set this way:

```
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" mode="StateServer"
              sqlConnectionString="SessionState" timeout="45" />
```

role maneger (the system does keep roles on cookies too):

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SCAProvider" 
             cookieRequireSSL="false" cacheRolesInCookie="true" 
             cookieTimeout="45" cookieProtection="All">
```

authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="AutenticacaoNFo" protection="All" requireSSL="false"
                 slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="login.aspx" path="/" 
                 timeout="45" />
</authentication>
```

Here's the part of the code where the problem happens...according with the stackTrace:

---

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender,
FormsAuthenticationEventArgs  args){

  if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
  {

    if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
    {
      try
      {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(
          Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

        args.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
          new Samples.AspNet.Security.MyFormsIdentity(ticket),
          new string[0]);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        // Decrypt method failed.
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {

    throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not " +
                            "supported for this application.");
  }
}
```

---

It might be a simple thing that i'm missing....but I really couldn't see the error...
Thank you for your time.

PS.: The webSite still work on any browser, as usual, except on Windows 8 IE.

Comment: Are cookies enabled in IE configuration? http://www.arecookiesenabled.com/

Comment: Try adding a `cookieless="UseCookies"` attribute to your forms element inside authentication too. Default is `UseDeviceProfile` which may or may not use cookies.

Comment: Yeas Marcus, I already changed the configs of IE. All of'em, but still crashing at all.

SO Joachim, the cookieless="UseCookies" atribute must be on SessionState and Authentication tags too?

I'll try it tomorrow (that's when the support team will give me the Tests environment).

If it works, i'll post here

thanks